# Por que a instrução não está a ser executada?

Tags: c, matriz, if

Estou a criar um programa que ordena uma matrix de estruturas, em primeiro lugar ordena as linhas e vai a cada linha e organiza-a por colunas. Na matriz que estou a utilizar ao fim de dois ciclos o valor de `(i+1 = 4)`, quando chamo de novo a funçao aux é suposto o (l=4 e o r=4) e não devia entrar dentro do if, alguem me sabe dizer porque?

```
void aux(int l, int r){
    int i;
    int auxx = 0;
    printf("%d, %d\n", l, r);
    if(l != r){
        for(i = l; i <= r; i++){
            if(matrix[i].line == matrix[i+1].line){auxx = auxx +1;}
            else{
                if(auxx==0){aux(i+1, 4);}
                else{
                    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i+1, l, auxx+l, 4);
                    bubblec(l, auxx+l);
                    aux(i+1, 4);}
                }
            }
        }   
    }

aux(0, 4);
```

Comment: Se a ideia é ordenar, porquê a recursividade ? Isso acaba por complicar desnecessariamente a solução. E o que é suposto fazer a função `bubblec` ?